# Flutter Error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, dart-null-safety

I'm using the new dart version <2.13.0-107.0.dev> with null safety enabled.

With this List of tasks:

```dart
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'find a way to live happy'),
    Task(name: 'Listen to music!!!'),
    Task(name: 'Live in the other world till ur power is off'),
  ];
```

when I try to use it in a ListView.builder constructor like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         TaskTile(
          taskTitle: tasks[index].name,
          isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,
          checkboxCallback: (bool? checkboxState) {
            setState(() {

              tasks[index].toggleDone();
            });
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I get this error:

***error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.***

and this error in the Run log:

***Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.***

For more info, the Task class is defined as follows:

```dart
class Task {
  String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name = '', this.isDone = false});

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You forgot to use `return` in your `itemBuilder`.

Use

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return TaskTile(...); // <-- 'return' was missing 
  },
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You are not returning the `TaskTile` widget:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tasks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     TaskTile(
```

should be:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tasks.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return TaskTile(
```